# How to convert multi-site to single site

Tags: multisite, migration, single

I need to take a site that is installed as a subdomain blog on a multi site install and move it to it's own domain on a standalone wordpress installation.

How can this be done?

I am running into trouble with the path to the images in posts because multi site uses `/blogs.dir/blogid/`

Can this be done?

Comment: Of course it can be done. Just export the subdomain install and import it on a new site. It will move the images it self

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I have not tested a use case such as yours.

If the trouble is with path to the images in the posts and other you can give [WordPress OneClick Migration](https://github.com/azizur/wordpress-oneclick-migration) a try. It was designed with Database level migration but it should work. You may need to run it in forced mood. See the [Readme file](https://github.com/azizur/wordpress-oneclick-migration/blob/master/README.md) for full details.

Comment: that looks like it will do the job. I ended up doing it myself all manually by doing mysql dumps on the site database and on the global database and then doing a search/replace perl command on the .sql files to change from wp_1_ to wp_ and ignored the options table.

Answer (score 1):

Use the WordPress export file, then install a fresh system and import the file again. This is the easiest way I know.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the current blog you want to move go to:

**Tools > Export**
[image: Tools Export]
**Select All Content**
[image]
This will create a `.xml` file with the name of the site and the date. 
Next setup your single site install and then go to:

**Tools > Import**
[image: Tools Import]
**Choose WordPress** (you may need to install this)
[image: Choose Wordpress]
**Choose All Content**
[image: Select All Content]

When you click continue it will show you a new page to map users or create new ones do what ever you want. Note that this will only work for people who have posted. Then make sure to tick the check box Download and import file attachments.
[image: Map Users And Download Attaments]